# VideoView stopping on Dialog Open of anykind

Tags: android

I have a video view in an activity.

```
private void videoInit() {
    videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);

    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            videoView.start();
            mp.setLooping(true);

        }
    });

    videoView.setVideoPath("android.resource://com.aplos.ideliver2/raw/iphone_inner_animation");//src/main/res/raw
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();
}
```

This is my function, and the dialog is opened with an intent to the other class.

This is executed for a scenario.

```
private void processError(Response mResponse) {
    try {
        AlertDialog.strMessage = mResponse.getResponseMessage();
        AlertDialog.strTitle = "Alert";
        AlertDialog.strButtonTitle = "OK";
        startActivity(new Intent(context, AlertDialog.class));
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        H.Handle(e);
    }
}
```

When the dialog is opened the video stops. I want to have the video running continuosly.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    videoView.stopPlayback();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    videoView.stopPlayback();

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    videoView.start();
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    videoView.start();
}
```

Comment: If you want anything to work in background also then you need to use service instead of activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove these two

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
   super.onPause();
   videoView.stopPlayback();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    videoView.start();
}
```

And add

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
   super.onPause();
   videoView.stopPlayback();
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onResume();
    videoView.start();
}
```

Because onPause will be called when your window is even partially obscured, like a pop up appearing.

**Edit:** Since you asked me to explain why it works you need to understand the activty life cycle. OnStart() will be called when the activity is completly not visible to the user, but onPause will be called when the activity is even partially invisible, like an alert box showing on the activity, or when you pull down to see your notifications etc.

To know more about activity life cycle check [this out](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ProcessLifecycle)

Comment: After onPause, the Activity is Resumed so onResume is called, even then the video dosent start.. Why ?

Comment: Perfect, it worked. Thanks alot. But do explain me the cycle thing.

Comment: I have added an edit, and please do accept the answer if it worked

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
onStop() instead of onPause()
```

and

```
onRestart() instead of onResume()
```

Good Luck...!